# FCM integration in IOS swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

how to do FCM integration in ios framework. I have did and tested in application but i want to do in framework so that i can sell to someone to  use my code. The problem i'm facing when u create xcode project on touch framework you cannot enable APNS option. Can anypne get me out of this. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

**First thing is first:**

As you already stated that, you've successfully integrated FCM into your cocoa touch library, here one thing i wanted to suggest.

If you're shipping your solution as `framework` to third party. I'm assuming you are using *Cocoapod*. Declare the *Firebase* related `pods` (which you are using) as Dependencies. Cocoapod will automatically manage this dependency tree. If you are preparing just plain `framework` and included *Firebase* related frameworks within it, it's wrong. Because the third party developer cannot update the *Firebase* related frameworks while new SDKs are released. Another thing that, the third party developer may use firebase's other services which required them to integrate firebase sdks within their app. In that case duplicate class declaration error may arise.

**Enabling APNS**

Yes you cannot enable APNS from capability for touch framework. Instruct your third party developer to enable required fields for their project. Include it in your integration guide or README.md what ever you are using to help third party developer integrating your cocoa touch framework.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md

Conclusions:
The Firebase SDKs may be used from an embedded dynamic framework in your project (e.g. for code reuse purposes) only when Firebase is not used from the app directly.

The Firebase SDKs should never be used from vendor dynamic frameworks because the version of Firebase compiled into the dynamic framework will conflict with the versions compiled into the app or included in any app bundles.

Conclusions:
Using the Firebase SDKs in static frameworks and libraries is safe, meaning there will be no symbol collisions, for both vendor and in-app internal libraries.

If the static framework is used from an app and its extensions, then it will be copied to each target, increasing the app download size.

If the static framework is used from an app and its dynamic dependencies, then it will be copied in both the app and its dependencies, which will result in undefined behavior.